# Perl unziping whole folder

Tags: perl, unzip

I have a zip package containing 3 folders and I have to unzip the whole package at once. I spent 3 hours trying to do this in Perl but I failed. I have a code to unzip one file or iterate through the package but I feel there has to be some cleaner way of unziping a package. Is there one line command to do this ?

Ideally:

```
unzip "package.zip" => "directory"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include (relevant parts of) the code you already have. See also the [Question Checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

https://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Unzip::Burst

This module might be what you need. But next time please post what you've tried first.

Comment: Just a note to others that this is marked as experimental and one also has to download and include it in some cases. The default perl that ships with OSX Snow Leopard, for instance, doesn't include it. Would be awesome if this were included by default, though.